# Issue: WCF service receives first enum member value though input is different

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

**Background**

As part of my request to a WCF service, I'm passing in an enum value *Add* (see below for details), but the service implementation which uses a shared library's enum object (which is essentially the same and is mapped using AutoMapper), seems to only be able to read th first member i.e. Equal. In other words, the user inputs *Add*, but the service implementation gets an *Equal*.

**Details**

I have an enum defined as

```
[DataContract]
public enum MyOperator
{
    [EnumMember]
       Equal = 0,
    [EnumMember]
     Add = 1,
      [EnumMember]
Subtract = 2
}
```

This enum is a property on another Data contract as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyExpression
{
 [DataMember]
  public string Field {get;set;}

 [DataMember]
  public string Value{get;set;}

 [DataMember]
  public MyOperator Operator {get;set;}

}
```

Finally this is contained in my request body:

```
[DataContract]
public class RequestBody
{
...

public MyExpression Expression {get;set;}
...
}
```

The corresponding enum object lies in a shared library and is defined as:

```
    public enum MyOperator
    {
           Equal = 0,
           Add = 1,
       Subtract = 2
    }
```

During the debugging of the service implementation (which uses this shared library's MyOperator enum), the problem that I'm observing is that inspite of the user inputting Add as part of the Soap request, I still see Equal everytime.

I tried declaring `MyOperator` as a `KnownType`, but that hasn't seemed to help.

Thanks for any help! Let me know if you need additional details

Comment: Can you watch the raw HTTP request through Fiddler or SoapUI or something, to see if the value is actually coming through?

Comment: Yes, the value is coming through. For some reason, it's only in the implementation that the value seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to guess, but my first guess would be that's it's trying to translate the string "equal" to an int and it's failing and giving back 0 (default int) which is going to be equal in your case.

The only other thing I can think of off hand is that it might not be able to translate between the 2 enums since they would be in different namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

IT seems like your service is unable to find the value you are passing in the request and taking first value of enum. What you can do is update the definition of your WSDL and run the request again. This should resolved the issue, This worked for me, Let me know if it does not work.